# For a given sparse matrix, how can I multiply it with a given vector of binary values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have a sparse matrix and another vector and I want to multiply the matrix and vector so that each column of the vector where it's equal to zero it'll zero the entire column of the sparse matrix.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you using `scipy` sparse matrices? What kind?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Yep, I'm using csr_matrix

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention anything about how the array and matrix are defined, it can be assumed that those are `numpy` matrix and array...
Do you mean something like the following?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

A = csr_matrix([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 5]])
v = np.array([1, 0, 1])
print(A.dot(v))
```

if so take a look at here:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: OK so this is basically what I'm doing today but I'm using this dot operation over ~1000 matrices where each matrix is about 15,000 X 100,000 so it takes ages (I'm doing it in parallel and still it takes so much time).
I'm looking for a way to simply reset specific columns of the matrix instead of fully multiply it, is it possible somehow?

Comment: @Lior, you should have provided this information in the question itself.  In other words, tell us what you did and what was wrong with it.  Matrix multiplication is a relative strong point for `csr`.  In fact row and column sums are done with it, as is some indexing.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the size of your problem and the fact you're using Python which is on the order of 10-100x slower for matrix multiplication than some other languages. Unless you use something like Cython I don't see you getting an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the speed of matrix multiplication, then you have to consider modification of the matrix attributes directly.  But depending on the format that may be slower.

To `zero-out` columns of a `csr`, you can find the relevant nonzero elements, and set the `data` values to zero.  Then run the `eliminate_zeros` method to remove those elements from the sparsity structure.

Setting columns of a `csc` format may be simpler - find the relevant value in the `indptr`.  At least the elements that you want to remove will be clustered together.  I won't go into the details.

Zeroing rows of a `lil` format should be fairly easy - replace the relevant lists with `[]`.

Anyways with familiarity of the formats it should possible to work out alternatives to matrix multiplication.  But without doing so, and doing sometimes, I could say which ones are faster.